# How to open a track without changing the playlist on foobar2000?

Tags: music, media-player, foobar2000

I would like to make [foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) my default media player but whenever I open a song my current playlist is replaced, it's not added to the current playlist. How do I change that?

Comment: It has been a long time ago since I used foobar, but I think from the playlist, there's an add button which you can use. And there might be a setting to not clear the list when using the explorer. From explorer you can also right click, and add to foobar I believe.

Comment: I only get Play in foobar2000 in explorer.

Answer (score 2):

In Preferences > Shell Integration, check "Set 'Enqueue' as the default action".

[image]